# PhpStorm only show Errors from Inspections

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm how can I only show Errors, not Warnings globally for all files etc.?

I only can find the Inspection area in Preferences, but there I would have to uncheck all warnings, minor warnings for all Checkboxes and had to manage this for new file types in the future.

So, how can I Globally only show errors like it was possible in the past with Inspection Levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can't be done in one click, but there's still a way. Open your inspections (*File | Settings | Editor | Inspections*), create a new inspections profile, e.g. "Errors only". Use filtering options to select all the inspection types but "Errors":

[image: Inspections]

Then click on a top inspection name/group and then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> on a bottom one to select all of them:

[image: inspections selected]

Then press Space 2 times to remove all checkboxes. Save the profile.
Voilà! You now have a "Errors only" profile that you can use for this project when needed.